# Free opc ua server with model import feature

Tags: c#, xml, opc, opc-ua

I want to implement OPC UA communication for my application (c#)

I found some OPC UA server simulations (Prosys and Softing OPC UA) I can connect and read data without problem. What I want is to implement euromap 77 standards.
http://www.euromap.org/euromap77

As far as I understand I must use model structure when accessing data via OPC. 
I want to load this model to OPC UA server and work on that data structure is it possible to import this http://www.euromap.org/files/Opc_Ua.EUROMAP77.RC1_00.NodeSet2.xml model to any free OPC UA server ?

Answer (score 5):

The OPC Foundation has sample servers with node managers that import NodeStateCollections, aka predefined nodes.

Take a look at [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard)

You can use the "UaNodeSetHelpers" class to convert from NodeSet2 files to NodeStateCollections.

```
// First, read a NodeSet2.xml file from a stream.
var nodeSet = UANodeSet.Read(istrm); 

// Then create an empty NodeStateCollection.
var nodes = new NodeStateCollection();

// Update namespace table
if (nodeSet.NamespaceUris != null && context.NamespaceUris != null)
{
   for (int ii = 0; ii < nodeSet.NamespaceUris.Length; ii++)
   {
       context.NamespaceUris.GetIndexOrAppend(nodeSet.NamespaceUris[ii]);
       namespaceUris.Add(nodeSet.NamespaceUris[ii]);
    }
}

// Update server table
if (nodeSet.ServerUris != null && context.ServerUris != null)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < nodeSet.ServerUris.Length; ii++)
    {
        context.ServerUris.GetIndexOrAppend(nodeSet.ServerUris[ii]);
    }
}

// Convert the nodeset to nodeState collection, aka predefinedNodes. 
nodeSet.Import(context, nodes);
```

```

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/3c1159ec712db4403d2dc9840b3e9525f56610b3/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Schema/UANodeSetHelpers.cs#L113

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/cd4173aa95abd296578b976be67485c299473a70/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Schema/UANodeSetHelpers.cs#L113

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I will try it now. I will have to replace nodeset with my own right ? that's all ?

Comment: As far as i know the SampleServer is only able to load PredefinedNodes.xml (e.g. from ModelCompiler), but not NodeSet2.xml (from OPCUAModeler), depending on the variant structure of the both xml files

Comment: Thanks @Houve for reminding me to fix my answer. The boiler example was not loaded from a nodeset2 file. Do you think the helper function would work for you?

Comment: @ Andrew Cullen Yes, the code worked for me, thank you very much! Searched for days for a solution in order to load the opcua-modeler .xml file into the opcua server directly.