# Get compilation output by ModelCompiler into .NET OPC-UA Server

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua

I used the ModelCompiler from [1] to compile my information model. Now, I am looking for a way to import the information model into my .NET Server (based on the .NET Core Server Sample from [2]) including the .NET OPC-UA Stack as NuGet package [3].

The Boiler, MemoryBuffer, and TestData samples use a dedicated node manager (which inherit from SampleNodeManager). My first idea was to write such a dedicated node manager (which inherits from CustomNodeManager2) for my information model, but this seems to be complicated.

There seem to be simpler ways than writing a node manager (cf. [4] for node.js servers). The .NET implementation offers some methods to parse the files containing the predefined nodes [5] or alternatively the NodeSet2 file [6] to NodeStateCollection.
Which steps are needed with the parsed NodeStateCollection to make the nodes known to the .NET Server?

```
[1] https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler
[2] https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard
[3] https://www.nuget.org/packages/OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua/
[4] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866428/how-can-i-generate-a-server-addressspace-from-a-xml-nodeset-file/
[5] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983225/populating-opcua-address-space-with-nodes-from-an-xml-schema/
[6] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944903/free-opc-ua-server-with-model-import-feature/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you have to write an own Server (inherit from StandardServer) and an own NodeManager (inherit from CustomNodeManager2), but this is not a lot of effort...

- add all output files of Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe to your solution either as class file or as embedded resource
- implement the Server to load your types via reflection

```cs
server.Factory.AddEncodeableTypes(this.GetType().Assembly);
```

- implement the NodeManager

```cs
SetNamespaces(MyNamespace.Namespaces.DataTypes);
//...
NodeStateCollection predefinedNodes = new NodeStateCollection();
predefinedNodes.LoadFromBinaryResource(context,"MyNamespace.DataTypes.Types.PredefinedNodes.uanodes", this.GetType().Assemly, true);
```

For full example, please look at:

- [DataTypesServer Implementation](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/SampleApplications/Workshop/DataTypes/Server/DataTypesServer.cs)
- [DataTypesNodeManager Implementation](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/SampleApplications/Workshop/DataTypes/Server/DataTypesNodeManager.cs)